# How would ++*ptr++ be evaluated by compiler if ptr is ptr to first element of a static array?

Tags: c++, pointers, operators

What is the order of evaluation in `++*ptr++`? Does it change when pointers and lvalues are involved in the operation?

If the precedence of `a++` is higher than `*a` or `++a`, then why is `++*a++` evaluated as first returning the incremented value then changing the pointer, rather than changing the pointer, then incrementing the value at the location.
Refrence for Precedence: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

```cpp
arr = {9, 99, 999 };
int *ptr = arr;
std::cout << ++*ptr++ << '\t';
std::cout << *ptr;
```

I expected the output to be 100    100, but the actual output was 10    99.

Comment: Instead of endlessly analyzing unreadable code, write readable code. <g>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The postfix increment `a++` increments the pointer ptr, but returns the copy of ptr before the operation (see difference between prefix/postfix).
So it can be rewritten (as noted in Quimby's answer) as ++(*(ptr++)) and goes like:

1. ptr++ : increments ptr so that it points to 99, but returns another pointer that still points to 9
2. *ptr++ : dereferences, evaluates to 9
3. ++*ptr++ : increments the value pointed to by the copied pointer, meaning increments 9 and returns 10

Here the logic behind pre/post increment/decrement is explained well:

> Pre-increment and pre-decrement operators increments or decrements the value of the object and returns a reference to the result.
>   Post-increment and post-decrement creates a copy of the object, increments or decrements the value of the object and returns the copy from before the increment or decrement.

From: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

Comment: So if were to say overload the pre-increment and post-increment operators for a class say A, and make the copy constructor of A, then would the post increment give an error?

Comment: why would it? When you write an operator for a user defined type it will only be used when you call it. BTW, I recommend trying it on your own rather than believing me :)

Answer (score 2):

Postfix operators have higher precedence that prefix so they BIND tighter/first so: `++*ptr++` is the same as `++(*(ptr++))` which boils down to what operand works on what. So postfix ++ will be applied to your 'ptr' pointer but 'after' first std::cout line. Prefix ++ will work on dereferenced ptr so this all is the same as:

```
int arr[] = {9, 99, 999 };
int *ptr = arr;
++(*ptr); // 9+1=10
std::cout << *ptr << '\t';
ptr++; // now ptr points to 99
std::cout << *ptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, because `++*ptr++` is rewritten as `++(*(ptr++))`

The rules in the link are quite clear:

1. The postfix ++ has highest precedence =>  `++*(ptr++)`
2. The prefix ++ and * have the same precedence and they are right-associative => `++(*(ptr++))`

The expression can also be split into individual statements like this:

```
arr = {9, 99, 999 };
int *ptr = arr;
int *ptr2 = ptr++;//ptr2 still points to the first element
int val = *ptr2; // 9
int incVal= ++val; // 10
```

Hopefully it's clear that the `ptr` now points to the second element of the array and the result of the expression is the incremented value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a single dimensional array

`++*ptr` referred to increment in pointer ptr to  0 elements of array, after incrementing the output for this will be 10

The postfix `++` has highest precedence => `++*(ptr++)`